# Having a ngrx root state with feature states in each lazy loaded angular module

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

I have multiple lazy loaded angular modules and One root module.
Can i have independent ngrx root store in each angular module, each store having its own feature states ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course this can be done, it is even the recommonded way to do. Read here:

https://medium.com/@AnkurRatra/lazy-loading-of-modules-with-ngrx-store-4th-version-angular-2-23c93295d4e8

You find an example here:
https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-NgRx-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Demo5